# Exporting and saving csv files to worksheets in excel workbook using python code ( version Python 3.11 )

Tags: python

I am trying to export the csv files into designated excel workbook creating new worksheet for each csv file. Csv files are generated from the broker website each 5 min for a limited number of runs.
Data in csv files represents the stock details (last price, change % , volume, etc.).I have a python
code that works good up to the point when csv files are created. I was trying to add new lines that will pick up csv files and export them to new worksheets every time the new csv is generated. The name of worksheets should correspond to the name of csv file. I found some code on the net that explains how to do it and added this portion to my code. But didn't work as I getting name error message: Name 'f_name' is not defined

Here is my code:

```
    import time
    import requests
    import glob
    import csv
    import openpyxl
    import os

    wb = openpyxl.Workbook()

    delay = 300
    max_writes =11

    URL = "https://company name.com/export.ashx?  v=141&f=sh_float_u100,sh_price_u20,sh_relvol_0.1to500,ta_change_-15to100&ft=4&auth=brat_stosic@yahoo.com"
    response = requests.get(URL)

     for i in range(max_writes):
     response = requests.get(URL)
     if response.ok:
        with open(f"export_{i+1}.csv", 'wb') as file:
             file.write(response.content)

# the upper portion of code works great;I have problem with lower portion

     for filename in glob.glob("C:/Users/Stosic Family/Python/export_{i+1}.csv"):
     (f_path, f_name)= os.path.split(filename)
     (f_short_name, f_extension) = os.path.splitext(f_name)
     ws = wb.add_sheet(str(f_short_name))
     spamReader = csv.reader(open(filename, 'rb'), delimiter=',',quotechar='"')
     row_count = 0
     for row in spamReader:
     for col in range (len(row)):
        ws.write(row_count,col,row[col])
     row_count +=1

     wb.save("C:/Users/Stosic Family/Python/dtest.xlsx")

     time.sleep(delay)
```

Message '''Name 'f_name' is not defined'''

Not sure what does it mean and how can I define f_name ? Also not sure what should I do with other
functions ( f_path;f_short_name )? Do I need to define them as well ? All I want is to create a worksheet(s) with name "export_{i+1}.csv" to the excel file "dtest.xlsx".
Really, new to Python and will really appreciate any help/suggestions

Thank you,

Bratislav

Here is my full code :

```
        import time
        import requests
        import csv
        import openpyxl
        import os
        import glob
        
        
        
        delay = 300
        max_writes =11
        
        URL = "https://company name.com/export.ashx?v=141&f=sh_float_u100,sh_price_u20,sh_relvol_0.1to500,ta_change_-15to100&ft=4&auth=brat_stosic@yahoo.com"
        response = requests.get(URL)
        
        for i in range(max_writes):
            response = requests.get(URL)
            if response.ok:
                with open(f"export_{i+1}.csv", 'wb') as file:
                     file.write(response.content)
        
        
        wb = openpyxl.Workbook("C:/Users/Stosic Family/Python/dtest.xlsx")
        
        for filename in glob.glob("C:/Users/Stosic Family/Python/export_1.csv"):
            f_name = os.path.split(filename)[1]
            f_short_name = os.path.splitext(f_name)[0]
            (f_short_name, f_extension) = os.path.splitext(f_name)
            ws = wb.add_sheet(f_short_name)
            spamReader = csv.reader(open(filename, 'rb'), delimiter=',',quotechar='"')
            for rno,row in enumerate(spamReader):
                for cno,col in enumerate(row):
                   ws.write(row_count,cno,col)
               
        
        wb.save("C:/Users/Stosic Family/Python/dtest.xlsx")
        
        time.sleep(delay)
```

However, still doesn't work, here is the message

```
    ws = wb.add_sheet(f_short_name) ^^^^^^^^^^^^
   
   AttributeError: 'Workbook' object has no attribute 'add_sheet'. 
   Did you mean: '_add_sheet'?
```

But, if I put '_add_sheet" still doesn't work. Any suggestions ?
Thank you,

Hi, here is the updated code :

```
    import time
    import requests
    import csv
    import openpyxl
    import os
    import glob
    
    
    
    delay = 300
    max_writes =11
    
    URL = "https://company name.com/export.ashx?v=141&f=sh_float_u100,sh_price_u20,sh_relvol_0.1to500,ta_change_-15to100&ft=4&auth=brat_stosic@yahoo.com"
    response = requests.get(URL)
    
    for i in range(max_writes):
        response = requests.get(URL)
        if response.ok:
            with open(f"export_{i+1}.csv", 'wb') as file:
                 file.write(response.content)
    
    
    wb = openpyxl.Workbook("C:/Users/Stosic Family/Python/dtest.xlsx")
    
    for filename in glob.glob("C:/Users/Stosic Family/Python/export_{i+1}.csv"):
        f_name = os.path.split(filename)[2]
        f_short_name = os.path.splitext(f_name)[0]
        (f_short_name, f_extension) = os.path.splitext(f_name)
        ws = wb.create_sheet(f_short_name)
        spamReader = csv.reader(open(filename, 'rt'), delimiter=',',quotechar='"')
        for rno,row in enumerate(spamReader):
            row_count = rno
            for cno,col in enumerate[row]:
               ws._writer(row_count,cno,col)
           
    
        wb.save("C:/Users/Stosic Family/Python/dtest.xlsx")
    
        time.sleep(delay)
```

Comment: The problem here is that your `glob` string will not match any files.  Thus, the `for` loop never runs, and `f_name` does not get created.  If you want a SPECIFIC file, then you don't need `glob` and you can use an f-string, like in your first sample.  If you want ALL files like that, use `glob.glob("C:/Users/Stosic Family/Python/export_*.csv")`.  Also, your indentation is quite wrong, and indentation is critical in Python.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering me. I modified my code and tried different options, however it didn't work. Here is my code:

Comment: import time
import requests
import csv
import openpyxl
import os




delay = 5
max_writes =3

URL = "https://company name.com/export.ashx?v=141&f=sh_float_u100,sh_price_u20,sh_relvol_0.1to500,ta_change_-15to100&ft=4&auth=brat_stosic@yahoo.com"
response = requests.get(URL)

for i in range(max_writes):
    response = requests.get(URL)
    if response.ok:
        with open(f"export_{i+1}.csv", 'wb') as file:
             file.write(response.content)

time.sleep(delay)

Comment: wb = openpyxl.Workbook("C:/Users/Stosic Family/Python/dtest.xlsx")

for i in range(max_writes):
    filename = ("C:/Users/Stosic Family/Python/export_{i+1}.csv")
    (f_path, f_name)= os.path.split(filename)
    (f_short_name, f_extension) = os.path.splitext(f_name)
    ws = Worksheet(wb),(str(f_short_name))
    wb._add_sheet
    spamReader = csv.reader(open(filename, 'rb'), delimiter=',',quotechar='"')

Comment: row_count = 0
    for row in spamReader:
        for col in range (len(row)):
            ws.write(row_count,col,row[col])
        row_count +=1

wb.save("C:/Users/Stosic Family/Python/dtest.xlsx")

Comment: What I get is : Worksheet not defined

Comment: Meanwhile, I tried different approach, instead of creating csv files I tried to import tables directly from the website into excel ( each run to create a new tab in dtest.xlsx. It worked, but not completely as I got data written just in rows not in rows and columns, like in csv files.

Comment: Here is my code:

Comment: import time
import requests
import pandas as pd

delay = 15
max_writes =3

Comment: URL = "https://company name.com/export.ashx?v=141&f=sh_float_u100,sh_price_u20,sh_relvol_0.1to500,ta_change_-15to100&ft=4&auth=brat_stosic@yahoo.com"
response = requests.get(URL)

df = pd.DataFrame(response)

Comment: with pd.ExcelWriter('dtest.xlsx')as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='test_1',index=False, header=False)
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='test_2',index=False, header=False)
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='test_3',index=False, header=False)

time.sleep(delay)

Comment: So, all data is available, just like in csv, but it is sorted just in rows, not in rows and columns. Any idea, what should I do ? Thank you !

Comment: Have you checked the documentation?  It's called `create_sheet`, not `add_sheet`.

Comment: I replaced "add_sheet" with "create_sheet", seems that there is no problem with that, now  I have another error: Namerror : name  'row_count' is not defined. How can we define it ? I guess it directs code where to start to read the csv file. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm a bit disturbed that you can't see it.  Look at the code.  Which variable contains the row number?  Hint, there is one, but it's not `row_count`.

Comment: Hi, I have updated my code, ( it in my question section ),  no error message any more, however I get an expected results. First, my file "dtest.xlsx" doesn't get filled at all and my csv files ( export_1/export_2/export_3 and so on) are written on the same time ( no matter of delayed time in code ), they are empty but with message in them " export requests are limited to one per second ". It seems to me that it is a server response. Not sure why as the code makes one request for every period of delayed time ( in my case 300 s ). What is wrong ? How can I fix it ?

Comment: You don't have any delay.  You are making 11 calls to `requests.get` right in a row.  That's what they're complaining about.

Comment: I do have a delay, I always had, please take a look on the latest code posted in question section. Shorter code runs properly ( up to line 'file. write (response. content)' but if I want to run longer code ( full code ), than I have problems explained in previous comments.

Comment: Don't tell me you have a delay.  Look at your first few lines of code.  You do `requests.get`, then `for i in range(max_writes)` and `requests.get`.  That is going to do 12 requests in a row, unconditionally, with NO DELAYS.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown us how your code fits in to the overall program, but this is going to be closer to what you need:

```
 for filename in glob.glob("C:/Users/Stosic Family/Python/export_*.csv"):
     f_name = os.path.split(filename)[1]
     f_short_name = os.path.splitext(f_name)[0]
     ws = wb.add_sheet(f_short_name)
     spamReader = csv.reader(open(filename, 'rb'), delimiter=',',quotechar='"')
     for rno,row in enumerate(spamReader):
         for cno,col in enumerate(row):
            ws.write(row_count,cno,col)

 wb.save("C:/Users/Stosic Family/Python/dtest.xlsx")

 time.sleep(delay)
```

Comment: Hi Tim, I modified my code and it is in my question above, any suggestions ? Thank you